# PdfRenderer Error : java.io.IOException: cannot create document. Error: 3

Tags: android, pdfrenderer, parcelfiledescriptor

I am trying to convert PDF To image Bitmap.. and for that I am Using this Code Below.

```
pdfFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "imagepdf.pdf"

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            try {
                Uri uri = MainActivity.getUriFromFile(PdfExtrectorActivity.this,new File(pdfFile));
                final ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(
                        uri, "r");
                final FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bitmap;
            final int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                PdfRenderer.Page page = pdfRenderer.openPage(i);


                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);



                // close the page
                page.close();
            }

            // close the renderer
            pdfRenderer.close();
        }
```

when I send **ParcelFileDescriptor** to pdfRenderer it will throws exception

```
java.io.IOException: cannot create document. Error: 3
```

I found Some Link from GitHub issues. 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic/issues/15
but it wont help me.

Any Help Accepted. 
thank you.

Comment: `parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(
                        uri, "r");` Does that file exist already?

Comment: And what is `pdfFile`? Please tell us full path.

Comment: yes.. file is already exist and also not corrupted. opens properly in pdf viewer

Comment: And please tell the value of `uri.toString()`.

Comment: @greenapps please See edited ans. I had added pdf file Path at top of the code

Comment: Why not also tell/show us that the type is String? How about a needed permission in manifest? And one required at runtime?

Comment: had already converted to uri with using file provider .. with my function getUriFromFile

Comment: Yes. Everybody can see that. Repeat: `Please tell the value of uri.toString()`

Comment: `Error: 3` What is error 3?

Comment: content://dgflick.com.sampledemo.provider/external_files/imagepdf.pdf this is mu Uri

Comment: and error 3 is found in exception. thats why I ask question, because I didnt understand what is error 3. ass I also attached git hub link,

Comment: Please do a test where you try to open the uri yourself. Use `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); is.close();`

Comment: Are you shure PdfRenderer can handle content schemes? Try with `Uri.fromFile(new File(pdfFile))`

Comment: `and error 3 is found in exception.` Yes i saw that. I quoted it from there. But what does 3 mean? You should tell us of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my Problem solved with this solutions to convert Image Bitmap from PDF which are in SD card.,

And this will worked fine for me

```
  File file = new File(getCacheDir(), PDF_FILE_NAME);
        //if (!file.exists()) {
        // Since PdfRenderer cannot handle the compressed asset file directly, we copy it into
        // the cache directory.
        //InputStream asset = context.getAssets().open("imagepdf.pdf");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +  "/imagepdf.pdf");
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int size;
        while ((size = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
        output.close();
        //}
        ParcelFileDescriptor mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
        PdfRenderer renderer = null;
        if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                renderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
                Bitmap bitmap;
                final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                    PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

                    // say we render for showing on the screen
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                    myImageBitmap.add(bitmap);
                    // do stuff with the bitmap

                    // close the page
                    page.close();
                }

                // close the renderer
                renderer.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah. This has solved the issue for me too. Thank you.